# "Too many events" error when deleting a small number of Keen IO events

Tags: javascript, http, events, keen-io

We had an issue this morning that created duplicate events in keen (496 of them) and are trying to delete them. I have an extraction query that returns just those events. If I run it over the time period of this week, the delete returns an error:

`{"message": "There are too many events to perform this operation. You cannot delete a collection that has over 1000000 events. Your collection currently has 4834812 events.", "error_code": "TooManyEventsError”}`

I've narrowed the timeframe to the past 12 hours on the extraction and get the expected 496 events.... a little nervous about switching it to delete.

I’d like to clean up these events, but want to make sure I’m not going to remove events that I want to keep….

My filter for the extraction and the (soon-to-be-executed) deletion has an array of keen IDs (keen.id) that I would like to delete. However, there are many more events in the timeframe that don’t match the filter.

What spooked me was that initially I ran the delete over the past 2 days (or week) as the timeframe and it returned and error response because there were more than 100,000 events in the timeframe.

If I narrow down the timeframe, I want to make sure it only deletes the list of IDs in my filter, not all of the events in the timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure you are passing your filters and timeframe as query parameters, not in the content body. A common "gotcha" with [DELETE](https://keen.io/docs/api/#delete-events) requests is that while other API requests like queries and extractions allow you to put query parameters in the content body of your request, the [DELETE API](https://keen.io/docs/api/#delete-events) ignores the content body completely. That can result in the DELETE API interpreting your request as a request to delete the entire collection.
2. Check your filter syntax. The second "gotcha" is that if you flub up the syntax or the encoding on your filters, it can also result in them being ignored completely, which again the API can interpret as a request to delete the entire collection.

In fact, this error is one that you would receive if you were trying to delete a collection, not a subset of events. So it's likely that one of the two things above is the culprit.

Here's what the delete syntax should be:

`https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/events/COLLECTION_NAME?api_key=MASTER_KEY&filters=YOUR_FILTERS_HERE&timeframe=this_7_days`

A best practice is to test your filter & timeframe syntax by changing this request to a [count request](https://keen.io/docs/api/#count). Make sure the count is what you'd expect (e.g. filter on 1 event and make sure the count is 1). The count request syntax is:

`https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/queries/count?api_key=READ_KEY&event_collection=COLLECTION_NAME`

Finally, because deletes are irreversible, I recommend running an extraction so that you have an extra copy of deleted events. That way if you accidentally delete the wrong thing, you can re-load them. The extraction syntax looks like:

`https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/queries/extraction?api_key=READ_KEY&event_collection=COLLECTION_NAME&timeframe=this_7_days`

After successfully completing a count and an extraction with your specific filter and timeframe set, then you can go on to run the delete request.